# javaの基本データ型について

Tags: java

以下のコードはなぜコンパイルエラーになるのですか？

```
short s = 10;
s = s + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いったんint型に変換されてから演算が行われるからですね。

```java
s = (short)(s + 1);
```

とか

```java
s += 1;
```

とか

```java
s++;
```

であれば、コンパイルは通りますね

参考：
https://www.javadrive.jp/start/cast/index5.html